# Is there a way to do three-way video calling with Skype?

Tags: skype

can skype host a video call with 3 or more people. if so, how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no practical way to do video chat with multiple people using Skype. You could build something like [Skypeasurus](http://wiki.twit.tv/wiki/Equipment#Computers_and_monitors), but that is probably more expensive and complicated than you want.

Answer (score 4):

You can now. It is a new paid feature in Skype. There is a 7-day free trial. See [Skype - Group Video Calling](http://www.skype.com/intl/en-us/features/allfeatures/group-video-calls/)

For a free option, see [Google+ Hangouts](http://www.google.com/+/learnmore/).

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is host a **conference call**, which allows you to communicate with 3 or even more contacts at once. This article, [How to Make a Three-Way Call with Skype](http://www.ehow.com/how_2015260_thre--way-calls-with-skype.html), describes all the required steps in a straightforward way.

Comment: Does that work with video? I know it does for voice.